# Travis CI: Build error because of Android emulator config

Tags: android, travis-ci

I get this error building in Travis CI for my android app:

> The command "echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t
>   android-28 --abi armeabi-v8a -c 100M" failed and exited with 1 during
>   .

My travis file:

```
language: android
sudo: required
jdk: oraclejdk8
android:
  components:
    - tools
    - tools
    - platform-tools
    - build-tools-28.0.3
    - android-28
    - android-28
    - add-on
    - extra
before_install:
    - yes | sdkmanager "platforms;android-28"
    - mkdir "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses" || true
    - echo -e "\n8933bad161af4178b1185d1a37fbf41ea5269c55" > "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-license"
    - echo -e "\n84831b9409646a918e30573bab4c9c91346d8abd" > "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-preview-license"
    - echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t android-28 --abi armeabi-v8a -c 100M
    - emulator -avd test -no-audio -no-window &
    - android-wait-for-emulator
    - adb shell input keyevent 82 &
    - ./gradlew dependencies || true
before_script:
    - echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t android-28 --abi armeabi-v8a
    - emulator -avd test -no-skin -no-audio -no-window &   
    - android-wait-for-emulator
    - adb shell input keyevent 82 &
script:
    - ./gradlew build connectedCheck
    - "./gradlew clean build connectedCheck -PdisablePreDex --stacktrace"
before_cache:
    - $HOME/.gradle/caches/
    - $HOME/.gradle/wrapper/
    - $HOME/.android/build-cache
cache:
    directories:
        -$HOME/.gradle/caches/
        -$HOME/.gradle/wrapper/s
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this line work locally when you tried?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I am fairly new to CI and Travis. Any suggestions on how I could run locally? I am using windows 10 Home

Comment: Just try `echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t android-28 --abi armeabi-v8a -c 100M` in local bash (assuming you got paths set correctly for `android` executable

Comment: I get `Error: Flag '-t' is not vaid for 'create avd'.` when running it @MarcinOrlowski

Comment: So here you go. Now you proceed with your debugging quest. You need to check if by any chance `-t` is now replaced with some other switch to set the api level. If so, you edit your yaml to have valid invocation and you should be done. If not you need to find the invocation that works for results you need. If new switch is working for you but not working with travis, then you change your yaml to do ie `android -h` (or `--help`) and trigger travis run. It will fail but log should show what switches their version supports.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Thanks for your help, helped a lot. Managed to solve it after some fiddeling. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please post the solution as regular answer so it may be helpful to others too.